# C# Ошибка SQL Error 52 на другом компе

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Имеется программа на C# с базой данных (MS SQL), использую Visual Studio 2015.
Что делать? app.Config выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Clients.Properties.Settings.DataClientsConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataClients.mdf;Initial Catalog=DataClients;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Вот свойства:
[image: Все свойства]

Может нужно юзать SQL Server, вместо Windows?

[image: Выбор]

**На моем компьютере все работает, а на другом SQL Error 52.**
В чем проблема? Как решить?

Comment: Вы когда установили студию себе, вместе со студией поставили движок баз данных `LocalDB`. Локально вы к нему и обращаетесь, это видно в вашей `connectionString`. А на другом компе этой `LocalDB` не установлено, потому когда прогу там запускаете, она не видит локального движка БД и ругается.

Comment: Кстати говоря, нельзя просто так взять и переиспользовать файл *.mdf на другой машине. Чтобы подключиться к бд *.mdf надо иметь какую-то версию движка бд установленной, localdb или sql sever. А вот просто так взять скопировать файлик и подключиться к нему напрямую не получится.

Comment: Если вам нужна встраиваемая БД, то можно юзать sql server compact, но оно делает файлики *.sdf, а не *.mdf. Ну или SQLite или куча других альтернатив

Comment: Спасибо, все сделал.